# CocoaAction with RxSwift and UIAlertController

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, rx-swift

I'm trying to implement the current behavior with a textfield and a button:
1 - the textfield should be validated not realtime but only after tapping the button it has to show an error label for the validation error
2 - if the textfield is validate I have to show an uialertcontroller to cancel or continue the operation

I tried especially the second part with the following code but It works only the first time, if I tap cancel for example and I tap an other time the button it looks like disabled....no more taps are allowed.

```
            let action = CocoaAction {
            return Observable.create {
                [weak self] observer -> Disposable in
                let alertController = self.getAlertController()
                let ok = UIAlertAction.Action(NSLocalizedString("OK_BUTTON", comment: "OK_BUTTON"), style: .Default)
                ok.rx_action = CocoaAction { _ in
                    return self!.viewModel!.modify(self?.addressTextFiled.rx_text)
                        .doOnNext({ data in
                            if let data = data
                            {
                                self!.showMessage(data.message)
                            }
                        })
                        .map { _ in Void() }
                }
                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("CANCEL_BUTTON", comment: "CANCEL_BUTTON"), style: .Cancel) { (_) in }

                alertController.addAction(ok)
                alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

                self!.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                return NopDisposable.instance
            }
        }
        confirmButton.rx_action = action
```

For the first point do you have some advise?

Thanks to help me out!!

Comment: Can you double-check that `self!.viewModel!.modify` is completing? If it doesn't complete, it doesn't free up the action to be executed again.

Comment: What you mean? If it sends the completed event?

Answer (score 0):

In the viewModel the observable returned is:

```
    func modify() -> Observable<StatusResponse?>
{
    return input!.continueClick
        .withLatestFrom(requestData!)
        .flatMap{ [unowned self] (code, mail) -> Observable<StatusResponse?> in
            return self.provider.request(APIProvider.ModifyRequest(code, "A", mail))
                .mapObjectOptional(ModifyStatusResponse.self)
                .trackActivity(self.activityIndicator)
        }
        .retry()
        .shareReplay(1)
}
```

What does avoid the completion of the observable?